# DocumentDb partitioning with several partitions count

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm having several collections of different entities partitioned by PartitionKey property in one Database.
I'm creating new DocumentClient for each repository of entity and bind HashPartitionResolver to it:

```
var hashResolver = new HashPartitionResolver(partitionKeyExtractor, partitionCollectionsSelfLinks, hashGenerator:new HashGenerator());
client.PartitionResolvers[db.SelfLink] = hashResolver;
```

But when I'm trying to insert entities:

```
await _client.UpsertDocumentAsync(Database.SelfLink, entity);
```

some entities often get in wrong partition. I guess it may happen because of different partition count of each entity in one Database.

Does anybody know what can cause this problem and how can I solve it? Thanks for help!

Comment: I suggest that you add more details to get a response. I don't have anything for your particular problem, but it's a DocumentDB anti-pattern to store only one type of document in a collection, which it sounds like you may be doing. The recommended approach is to use a _type="user" field or _isUser=true field on each document.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.
After decompiling the code of HashPartitionResolver and ConsistentHashRing I found that ConsistentHashRing has this line:

```
byte[] hash = hashGenerator.ComputeHash(BitConverter.GetBytes(node.GetHashCode()));
```

but in another part of the code it has this line:

```
byte[] hash = hashGenerator.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(node));
```

so when I change the first one to

```
byte[] hash = hashGenerator.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(node));
```

everything works fine. I think this is because of hardware dependent BitConverter or GetHashCode method. Related issue in GitHub: [Different Partitioning Schemes in the same database](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/84#issuecomment-166952058)